# Serious bug: The last revision of drive.revisions.list doesn't return actual data in the document

Tags: google-drive-api

Hey Google Drive team we're hitting a problem where the latest revision doesn't seem to be returning us the same data as what is in the file

fileId: 0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc

I have created a sample test file which you can demonstrate the problem ( this file has no private information ).

Steps with which I hit this problem:

1) Get revisions for a file.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.revisions.list?fileId=0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc&fields=items(etag%252CexportLinks%252Cid%252ClastModifyingUser%252ClastModifyingUserName%252Cmd5Checksum%252CmodifiedDate)&_h=7&

2) Get the export link for the last revision
The revision with the problem - this is the latest revision:

{
   "etag": "\"Q5ElJByAJoL0etObruYVPRipH1k/ZLaqw94DLZauzYjKyyggCDlRDfY\"",
   "id": "1376261400102000",
   "modifiedDate": "2013-08-11T22:50:00.102Z",
   "exportLinks": {
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc&revision=1376261400102000&exportFormat=pdf",
    "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc&revision=1376261400102000&exportFormat=ods",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc&revision=1376261400102000&exportFormat=xlsx"
   }

1. Compare what is seen in Google Spreadsheets with what is seen in the export link

Expected behaviour: latest revision has the same data that shows up in drive
Actual behaviour: Latest revision doesn't have the data in drive.

This screenshot demonstrates the problem - in Google Spreadsheets, you can see a file which is non empty, and side by side you see the export link taken from above:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/ugc.letterfeed.com/115074632018380198157/9026814b8ff754744414a2c3ccf7bb1b.png

Expected behaviour: The latest revision has the same data as the data we see in drive

Actual behaviour: The latest revision isn't showing what is seen in Google Spreadsheets

Note that it is not 100% reproducible, but we seem to run into it multiple times and it is quite serious when we do run into it.

Comment: Also of note:

1. This is also reproducible with drive.revisions.list with revision set to "head"

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.revisions.get?fileId=0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc&revisionId=head&_h=2&

2. Drive.files.get does return an export link which is correct

If you need details, I will be happy to send you more details over email.

Comment: I think the last revision is just not being returned in revisions.list result at times.

modifiedDate of the last revision in drive.revisions.list
     "modifiedDate": "2013-08-11T22:50:00.102Z",

modifiedDate of the file as per drive.files.get:

     "modifiedDate": "2013-08-11T22:52:51.901Z",

It's as if the latest revision is not showing up in drive.revisions.list / drive.revisions.get which revision=head. At the time of me reproducing the problem, the file was changed over an hour ago, so it doesn't seem like any kind of propagation delay is involved.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been reproduced and reported.
Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Hi JunYoung, do you have any idea by when this will be fixed?